# How can I write combiner and partitioner in python for a Hadoop Map Reduce job? And how do I invoke this in my Hadoop Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How do I write a combiner and partitioner job in python and invoke it using Hadoop Streaming.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at [Pydoop](http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/). I have not explored this, but as per the documentation,

> Pydoop Script enables you to write simple MapReduce programs for
>   Hadoop with mapper and reducer functions in just a few lines of code.
>   When Pydoop Script isn't enough, you can switch to the more complete
>   Pydoop API, which provides the ability to implement a **Python
>   Partitioner, RecordReader, and RecordWriter**. Pydoop might not be the
>   best API for all Hadoop use cases, but its unique features make it
>   suitable for specific scenarios and it is being actively improved.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375861/fails-when-using-hadoop-streaming-with-python-combiner) is an SO question on the Python based **hadoop combiners**.

**Additional Reference**

[Reference Link](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/pydoop-writing-hadoop-programs-in-python/240156473)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/crs4/pydoop)

Also [this link](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/) details on various other available hadoop-python frameworks.

Comment: As far as I know,Pydoop cant be used for all applications and so I want to stick with hadoop streaming.Isn't there any way to implement the combiners and partitioners in Python other than Pydoop?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Yelp's [MRJob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob). It's straightforward and has a good docs, and as I used it myself - use same interfaces as Java libraries for hadoop. And yes, it is using hadoop streaming - performance may be the case. But, unfortunately, you still need to write **partitioner** on Java.